# namespace search in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I found a problem concerning namespace search. 
The following simplified code failed to compile:

```
namespace A {
  namespace B { 
    class Test {
    };
  }
  namespace C {
    namespace B {
      typedef B::Test AnAlias;
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler complains that Test in namespace `A::C::B` does not name a type.

The problem seems to be that the compiler sees a namespace B inside namespace C and does not no further search. I would have exspected that he also would look in namespace A (which is a enclosing namespace) and find the B::Test there.

If I rename `C::B` everything is fine.
If I qualify `A::B::Test` everything is fine.
If I put the typedef directly in namespace `A::C` everything is fine.

This behavior was tested with gcc 4.1 and intel 12 compiler. (both for linux).

Are the compilers right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't you do typedef ::A::B::Test AnAlias; to make it works? I think that compiler tries to resolve namespace in your current scope. ::A::B::Test will indicate that you're looking for global scope A::B::Test

Comment: Your forgot to close your namespaces with a `;` . Also, use `typedef typename B::Test AnAlias`

Comment: @TomKnapen: Namespaces don't have to be closed with a semicolon. And `typename` is also not relevant here.

Comment: @TomKnapen You don't close namespaces with a `;`. As for the actual question, it's just not how the name search algorithm is designed. That's all.

Comment: @BjörnPollex why is `typename` not relevant here? Test names a type, which as far as I know, requires to be typedef'd with `typename`?

Comment: @TomKnapen: No it doesn't. `typename` is used to disambiguate the names of dependent types in templates, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/).

Comment: class/struct definitions must be closed with a `;` cause a declaration may follow (heavily used in C) for example: `class A {} a;`

Comment: typename is required for template dependent names to indicate that a dependant type is meant. As far as I know it is only allowed in that context.

Comment: @BjörnPollex thank you for the interesting reading, it has definitely enriched my knowledge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `B` in `typdef B::Test` resolves to `A::C::B`.  If you're going to reuse the name `B`, you need to specify it to remove the ambiguity.  The compilers are behaving properly.  IIRC, names are resolved to the closest declaration to its use or reference.  In this case `A::C::B` is the closest declaration to the `typedef`.

Comment: You mean the declaration of `A::C::B` shadows `A::B` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "shadows"?

Comment: Similar as a variable in a inner scope shadows (or hides) a variable of the same name in an outer scope.

Comment: @andand: similarly to local variables I guess, `void foo(int i) { for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { ...`

Comment: @unknownfrog:  Okay.  I hadn't heard the term used in that context before.  Yes, that's what I mean.